# Реализация своего решения для wifi hotspot

Tags: linux, wifi, hotspot

Имеется задача, для реализации hotspot в санатории, после изучение материалов в открытых источниках сформировалось общая картина сего действия.

1. Дистрибутив *nix с двумя сетевыми интерфейсами eth0 - интернет соединение, eth1 - wifi router
2. FreeRadius для авторизации, Captive portal сервер , Apache+php.
3. 3.USB модем для отправки смс с паролем или же используя интернет сервисы для данной операции.

Хотелось бы узнать структуру, что зачем делать и как реализовать эти связки,может кто поделится ссылкой на свои реализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Любой подходящий Pi, например, raspberry или orange pi r1, raspbian или armbian на нём.
2. hostapd, FreeRADIUS, Apache, PHP, скрипт, разрешающий и запрещающий транзитный трафик по маку источника в зависимости от выполнения условий на нём.
3. USB-модем + gnokii там же для отправки SMS с паролем.

Чего тут рассказывать, вы уже всё написали, оставалось только ненужный отдельный wi-fi роутер из схемы выкинуть.

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял, то и все это дело будет крутится на PI, не нужно сервер ставить? И по поводу скриптов, они имеются в открытом доступе или же их самому придётся писать?

Comment: @ДмитрийТолкачев поняли правильно. Единственное — все Pi довольно привередливы к качеству питания, и microUSB — не лучшее из решений. Что касается написания скриптов — это по-любому не самая большая часть работы.

Comment: @ДмитрийТолкачев а, стоп! Санаторий! То есть вы хотите не где-то в уголочке возле барной стойки сделать хотспот с покрытием сто квадратных метров в единственном зале, а полностью покрыть сетью серьёзный санаторный жилой корпус с несколькими этажами и сотнями отдыхающих?

Comment: Необходимо покрыть главный корпус, в котором уже реализован безшовный роуминг, я планирую его как центральный сделать,чтобы через него авторизация шла.

Comment: "Организован роуминг" — то есть access points уже расставлены и покрытие более-менее протестировано?

Comment: да все верно вот и сомнения а потянет ли PI все это?

Comment: Точно не потянет. Я поначалу как-то не придал значения слову "санаторий", больше заметил "hotspot".  Так что ответ мой игнорируйте, он не про это. Хотя я по-прежниму вижу одним из вариантов машину в предложенной вами конфигурации (eth0 - аплинк, eth1 - вайфайный сегмент) в качестве шлюза для клиентов хотспота, причём вайфайные маршрутизаторы (если они маршрутизаторы) работают в режиме точек доступа (то есть мостами, не роутерами).

Comment: и вот я раньше таким не занимался и поэтому возник вопрос а как правильно и используя какое ПО организовать вот этот самый шлюз

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82085/discussion-between-alexander-prokoshev-and--).